# Sendgrid Web API -- set multiple users in reply_to field

Tags: email, sendgrid, reply

I'm using the Sendgrid Python library, and I'd like to send emails with multiple people in the 'reply_to' field.

I'd like to send an email to 2 people such that both users can email one another by hitting reply.  The simplest solution to this seems to be to put both users in the reply to field.

I haven't seen any way to do this in the Sendgrid docs -- they seem to only want a single email address string in their 'reply_to' field.  However, I know that emails with this characteristic are possible (please excuse the budget redaction job):

[image: Multiple entries in the reply-to field]

Anyway, as you can see, multiple entries in 'reply-to' are possible.  So does anyone know how to do it with Sendgrid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes that is possible to do with SendGrid. To add multiple 'reply-to' entries you have to use custom headers.

So in Python, you would add:

```
message.add_header("Reply-To", "user1@email.com, user2@email.com")
```

Comment: how to add that in web api?

Comment: message.headers["Reply-To"] = "user1@email.com, user2@email.com"

Comment: The V3 API does not allow to set the Reply-To header directly. See http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.headers error message "Header can not be one of the reserved keys.".

Answer (score 2):

As of today, there is no way to set multiple reply-to addresses. Here is the Github issue for sendgrid: https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/339

Comment: That link is now broken. For the C# library this was fixed in version 9.28.0. The OP is asking about Python though, maybe you could update your answer to include information about the Python library?

Answer (score 0):

This has been discussed as most wanted functionality as per this open [issue](https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-csharp/issues/339).
Now SendGrid supports to mention multiple emails in replyTo but they introduced a new header for this as mentioned in their [doc](https://docs.sendgrid.com/api-reference/mail-send/mail-send#multiple-reply-to-emails). Though this support is not available in many of their SDKs. **UPDATE: Now this feature is available with [Sendgrid Mail nodejs library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/mail/v/7.5.0).**

So I forked their code and did the changes. The changes are available on this [link](https://github.com/subinoy7/sendgrid-nodejs/tree/f/replyToMultiple) and soon I will raise a PR to merge this with their code base.

The send an email with multiple emails in replyTo, use the code snippet given below:

```js
const sgMail = require('@sendgrid/mail');
sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
const msg = {
  to: 'recipient@example.org',
  from: 'sender@example.org',
  subject: 'Multiple mail in replyTo',
  html: '<p>Here’s an example of multiple replyTo email for you!</p>',
  replyToList: [
        {
            'name': 'Test User1',
            'email': 'test_user1@example.org'
        },
        {
            'email': 'test_user2@example.org'
        }
    ],
};
```